# I have 2 different APIs response and need create new object from these two Api's response and needs return Flux

Tags: project-reactor

I have 2 different apis as NonBillableEmployee and Billable Employee. I want to add the nonbillable api responses and billable api responses  common values to  new object i.e. Employee object 
(common values are ename, etype, eid) and i need to return Flux

========== Dtos =======

```
public class NonBillableEmployee {
    List<NonBillableEmployeeDto> list;
      //setter and getter
 }
public class NonBillableEmployeeDto {
   String name;
   Long eid;
   String eType;
   //setters and getters
}

public class BillableEmployee {
     List<BillableEmployee> list;
}
public class BillableEmployeeDto {
    String name;
    Long eid;
    String eType;
}
```

========================== Logic =================

```
Flux<BillableEmployee> billable= webClient1.get().retrieve().bodyToFlux(BillableEmployee.class);
Flux<NonBillableEmployee> nonbillable= webClient2.get().retrieve()
                                         .bodyToFlux(NonBillableEmployee.class);

    Flux<Employee> f = Flux.zip(billable, nonbillable).flatMap(tuples->{

        List<BillableEmployee> l1 = tuples.getT1().list.parallelStream().collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<NonBillableEmployee> l2 = tuples.getT2().list.parallelStream().collect(Collectors.toList());

            //here how can we do it
        return Flux.just(new Employee());
})
```

Comment: I will get above 1000 records from each API response. How can do it better way